# Where can I find docs for TextMate grammars?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, textmate

I'm making a custom programming language. I wanted to make an VS Code **extension**, that will tokenize the language syntax. I also found out that it uses **TextMate grammars**. So I need to learn **how** to write a such grammar. And I can't find any documentation for TextMate grammars.

I've been searching internet for **days** and found some basic info like [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide), but I see that there's more through **JSON schema**. So i would appreciate official docs or reference that shows off **ALL** features. I've been looking literally everywhere and can't find anything else. Does anybody know where are these docs, or do they even exist??

Comment: The first link when googling "textmate grammar" is https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That link looks like can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for scope selectors in TextMate v1 can be found at https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars and https://macromates.com/manual/en/scope_selectors. For v2, at https://macromates.com/textmate/manual/language-grammars and https://macromates.com/textmate/manual/scopes.

If you want to look at examples, you can look at [the builtin extensions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions). For example [the one for HTML](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/html/syntaxes/html.tmLanguage.json).